# ffmpeg CMAF support for mpeg-dash

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mpeg-dash, libav, libavcodec

All,
I am trying remux an [mp4](https://test-videos.co.uk/vids/bigbuckbunny/mp4/h264/1080/Big_Buck_Bunny_1080_10s_30MB.mp4) as a segmented mpeg-dash stream. I am using libavcodec and the code is exactly like [leandromoreira's](https://github.com/leandromoreira/ffmpeg-libav-tutorial/blob/master/2_remuxing.c) example, updated to C++14. By setting

```
av_dict_set(&opts, "movflags", "frag_keyframe+empty_moov+default_base_moof", 0);
```

I get segmented mp4 files and an MPD to play them with. My question is how I get libav to store my files in a CMAF container? Is there some kind of flag for CMAF in libavcodec?